# Reload an activity from Service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-service

I have been trying to reload an activity from a android service. I have gone through many tutorials and documentations. However, I am not still getting it to work.

Scenario :  When the dashboard for my app is loaded, it starts a Service class , BackgroundDashboardService, which will fetch some data from a remote server using a web api and save that to a sqlite db. Once the data has been saved to the db, I need to reload the Activity so that the latest data is displayed.

This is what I have done so far.

In My Service Class I added the following code right at the end of OnStartCommand method which updates the local DB.

```
StopSelf ();
Intent intent1 = new Intent("DataRecieved");
LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent1);
}).Start();
```

And then added a Class that inherits from BroadcastReciever named MyBroadcastReciever.

```
[BroadcastReceiver] 
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        context.StartActivity(typeof(Dashboard));
    }
}
```

And finally added the following code in the OnCreate method in Dashboard Activity class.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).RegisterReceiver(
receiver, new IntentFilter("DataRecieved"));
```

I have also added the MyBroadcastReciever variable in the Dashboard class.

```
private MyBroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

When the dashboad page is loaded. I get the following error message.

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
  at at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
  at at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
  at at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: You have a NRE. Have you tried debugging the `OnReceive()` method? Are these objects null?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged and the value is null.

Comment: Is receiver an instance of MyBroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: @Softlion : Yes, it is

Comment: Instead of using RegisterReceiver, you could use the attribute method. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19448/example-for-broadcastreceiver-in-android